# iPhone MDM and private Data (Inventory vs. Private Device)

Tags: iphone, icloud, privacy, mdm, automated-device-enrollment

I'd like to ask if there is a difference how my personal data is managed on an iPhone.

1. Private Device (enrolled manual MDM): Separate APFS volume, restrictions for the company which data can be accessed and what is controlled on that device. Things are separated.
2. Inventory Device of the company (DEP enrolled MDM device): Can I use a private iCloud-Account on such device and data is separated like it's my own private property and because of it's a corporate device, they have a bit more rights things to do with it (wiping and so on) except of accessing my personal data?

Would be really helpful to know, can't find specific information about it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a company owned device and it has Microsoft InTune installed as the MDM your employer can see everything on the phone. If it’s your personal phone and you installed InTune to be able to access certain work stuff then they can still see everything by flipping a switch on their dashboard which switches the phone status from personal to company owned. This is so invasive that there are usually rules enforced by the threat of termination that prevent this from happening. But it can happen. InTune even gives itself more rights than Apple do in that if an officer of the law approaches your company and asks for access to the phone, a sympathetic company officer, or just someone who doesn’t like you can give them access. You don’t get a notification to the phone until after the access has been made.